# How should questions about Falskaar (Skyrim mod) be tagged?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

This is about how to tag questions related to [Falskaar](http://skyrim.nexusmods.com/mods/37994/), a Skyrim mod:

> Falskaar is a new lands mod that adds an entirely new worldspace to the world. It's accessed by a dungeon the first time, then by boat from then on out. Falskaar's goal was to act as a DLC, adding content in almost every area. There is a new land, places, people, quests, dungeons and more for the player to experience. It adds roughly 20+ hours of content, and favors all types of characters.

The first [Falskaar-related question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/125124/revisions) was retagged multiple times, until it settled down with both [skyrim](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/skyrim) and [skyrim-falskaar](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/skyrim-falskaar). That is until [skyrim-falskaar](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/skyrim-falskaar)  [mysteriously disappeared](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/revisions/125124/4) (was removed from all questions with the tag). I've been able to re-add [skyrim-falskaar](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/skyrim-falskaar) to all Falskaar-related questions after that. But recently, [skyrim-falskaar](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/skyrim-falskaar) was made into a synonym of [falskaar](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/falskaar). What's going on?

**How should questions about Falskaar (Skyrim mod) be tagged?**

Comment: The mysterious disappearance means that a moderator has merged the two tags. Merging rewrites history and doesn't produce a revision entry.

Comment: @MadScientist The mysterious disappearance has happened before  the [tag:skyrim-falskaar] tag was made into a synonym of the [tag:falskaar] tag. I was able to re-tag a question with [tag:skyrim-falskaar] before it was made a synonym. Is it possible that the tag was burninated?

Comment: Merging doesn't leave any public evidence behind, so I can only speculate. But when a mod creates a synonym there is an option to also merge the tags as well, I would have guessed that this is what happened here.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I propose that Falskaar-related questions be tagged with both [skyrim](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/skyrim) and [skyrim-falskaar](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/skyrim-falskaar), similar to [the tagging scheme of Skyrim DLC questions](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/skyrim-hearthfire+or+skyrim-dawnguard+or+skyrim-dragonborn+skyrim). Falskaar is a DLC-level content mod, and one of the biggest, if not, the biggest new lands mod for Skyrim.

[falskaar](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/falskaar) should then be made  a synonym of [skyrim-falskaar](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/skyrim-falskaar).

Comment: I expected a half-baked new land mod of the sort so common for Oblivion, but it's actually a finished mod! In that case, it will be popular and should have a [gamename-modname] tag, yes.

Answer (score -6):

Size alone should not be the determining factor as to whether a game or mod deserves a tag of its own. If there's questions about something, we're here to answer it.

That said, Falskarr is not an official DLC of Skyrim. Therefore, it should just be tagged [skyrim](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/skyrim)+[falskaar](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/falskaar) to differentiate it from the three official DLC are (and it really needs a tag-wiki in any case), just as Day-Z questions are **not** tagged with Arma II.

Comment: is Falskaar a total conversion with new mechanics, like Nehirim for Oblivion or Day-Z? I was under the impression that it was just new maps/landmass/quests/items, which is a *bit* of a different case from Day Z w/r/t dropping the main game tag entirely.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz Yes, I've been waffling on that point back and forth. I've retracted that suggestion.

Comment: your edit is unclear - you say you've retracted the suggestion, but the edit reads like you've doubled down on it.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz Ah, I see. Fixed.

Comment: You cannot play normal Arma 2 from inside Day-Z, but you can (and must) play normal Skyrim while playing Falskaar. I think that's a bad reason. As a relatively new user, I find it much simpler if a mod is tagged with the game's name in it; in this case skyrim-falskaar.